# Round Robin for several consumers in KAFKA is not working

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have 5 separate docker images: 1 for kafka broker, 1 zookeeper, 1 producer and 2 consumers.
I publish messages to the topic via the producer.
Basically, I would like that the messages will be consumed in a round robin algorithm,
so for that purpose I defined the consumers with the same `group.id` and added config of `partition.assignment.strategy` to be `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor`,

but I find that only 1 consumer receives all of the messages.

My Producer Code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.Producer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;


public class DiscoveryKafkaProducer{
   Producer<String, String> producer;

   public DiscoveryKafkaProducer(Properties configs) {
   producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(configs);   
}

   public void send(String topic, List<String> records) {
   for(String record: records){
       producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(topic, record));
   }
   producer.flush();
}
```

My Consumer Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String server = "lshraga-ubuntu-sp-nac:9092";
    Properties consumerConfigs = new Properties();
    consumerConfigs.put("bootstrap.servers", server);
    consumerConfigs.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    consumerConfigs.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    consumerConfigs.put("group.id", "discovery");
    consumerConfigs.put("client.id", "discovery");
    consumerConfigs.put("partition.assignment.strategy", "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    DiscoveryKafkaConsumer consumer1 = new DiscoveryKafkaConsumer(Collections.singletonList(topicName), consumerConfigs);
    
     try {
         while (true) {
            System.out.println("Start to consume");
            consumer1.poll(1000L);
         }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
 public class DiscoveryKafkaConsumer {

       Consumer<String, String> consumer;
       Integer id;
       public DiscoveryKafkaConsumer(List<String> topics, Properties configs) {
       consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configs);
       consumer.subscribe(topics);
       }


   public DiscoveryKafkaConsumer(int i, List<String> topics, Properties configs) {
       consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, String>(configs);
       consumer.subscribe(topics);
       this.id = i;
}

   public void poll(long timeout) throws InterruptedException {

       ConsumerRecords<String,String> records = consumer.poll(timeout);
       System.out.println("Hey!Consumer #" + id + "got records:" + records);
       Map<String, List<String>> results = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
       records.forEach((cr) -> {
    

   System.out.println("cr.topic()=" + cr.topic());
       List<String> list = results.get(cr.topic()); 
       if(list == null) {
           list = new ArrayList<>(); 
           results.put(cr.topic(), list);
           }
            list.add(cr.value());
            System.out.println("list=" + list);
       });
```

}

I'm using kafka-clients version 0.11.0.0.

What do I need to add/configure in order to consume the messages in a Round Robin manner?

Comment: How many partitions does your topic have?

Comment: I didn't touch the partitions number

Comment: to check partitions count run : ~/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeprURL --describe --topic  topic_name

Comment: Actually, I'm working with kafka docker image and I changed the partition number to 2,  KAFKA_NUM_PARTITIONS: 2
and now I see that the messages are dispatched in round robin, How can I update the partition number in a code?

Comment: i don't know exactly about your image. Kafka itself allows you to specify number of partitions when you create new kafka topic and increase number later

Comment: Do you know how to increase the number of partitions dynamically in java?

Answer (score 0):

It's not still possible to increase the number of partitions from Java. There is the KIP-195 and the related PR which should be included in the next releases : https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-195%3A+AdminClient.createPartitions